# node.js application without or with nginx/apache

Tags: nginx, https, node.js

I am starting a REST server using node.js with the restify framework. There will, therefore, be no static pages. However, ssl (https) will be required. Is it a good idea to put an http server in as a go between or is that an unnecessary complication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that NodeJS (or ruby, or python, or perl, ...) is not a web server (regardless of the awesomeness of libraries such as express.js, socket.io, ...) , and can't compete with nginx, apache, lighttpd, ... at the very least in terms of reliability.

Running NodeJS services, I would recommend using:

- `nginx` serving HTTPS (your HTTP headers, CSP policy, ...)
- `PM2` driving your NodeJS processes (you'll be able to cluster them, clustered process can be reloaded in a way that would shorten service interruption, ...)

Then again, using NodeJS as a frontend [isn't unusual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050704/can-node-js-fully-replace-solutions-like-apache-or-nginx).

Comment: I actually independently went with this exact solution. I feel a little better about the extra hop with nginx.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not easily answerable. In fact it all depends on your personal requirements. Adding another component to your landscape might give you more flexibility and scalability (that you might not need) for the cost of possible maintenance, license or support costs, capabilities, availability and what not.

Technically, you can both use either the `tls` package of Node.js for the encryption handling or let e.g. nginx handle this for you and proxy the requests to node.js where applicable.

In my opinion there is no definite "right" or "wrong". You should just compare advantages and disadvantages and base your opinion on the outcome.

If I were to setup something like that, I think I'd rather put an nginx in the middle. It's pretty easy to setup and won't consume too much resources for such a small job on the one hand side (so the overhead isn't too big), on the other hand side you gain some more flexibility (e.g. for serving static content such as images directly, load balancing between additional future instances or serving only a single domain via node.js).

However, if you want the simplest setup and minimize future maintenance (e.g. installing new versions of your proxy), you may go another way.